# Proxy wss in webpack

Tags: websocket, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have a project built on top of Angular 5.

I want proxy websocket when running `ng serve`. There is a websocket server, i can connect to it using address `wss://myserver/ws` but can't setup proxy.

```
{
    "/ws": {
        "target": "wss://myserver",
        "secure": false,
        "ws" : true
    }
}
```

That config doesn't work. I can proxy https request but can't do websockets

How to fix this?

Comment: Having a similar issue to you, but one thing I discovered is that when I proxied the path `/ws` it interfered with Webpack's HMR connection. I changed it to another path and I got new errors.